# Configuring Eclipse with Sparkling Water

Tags: eclipse, homebrew, pydev, sparkling-water

My objective is to use Eclipse for coding Sparkling Water on Mac.

I have been able to install Java, Scala, Spark 2.2 with Brew install, Sparkling water as binaries and have been actively coding on Jupyter notebook. I have also been able to successfully install Eclipse, PyDev and configure it with Anaconda's Python interpreter.

What I have not been able to do is to configure Eclipse for either Spark or Sparkling water. The issue is two fold:

1. Brew install does not have .zip or .egg file that can be used as Python interpreter.
2. Brew does not create env variables in /Users//bash_profile folder. I suppose this can be solved by manually adding the env variable.

I am following directions from https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/

Can someone please provide directions for configuring eclipse with brew installs?

Comment: Just FYI, the Sparkling Water developers use IntelliJ rather than Eclipse.  So you might have better luck getting an answer to that question instead.

Comment: Please have a look on the development documentation first - http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.2/latest-stable/doc/devel/devel.html. 

Sparkling Water can be used in any IDE you favor

Comment: I do not think this document has specifics on how to setup for Python interpreter IDEs. Please correct me if I am wrong.